# Find the longest parent-child chain in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

**Scenario**

I have a dataframe. Each row contains an item, which can be but not necessarily linked with a parent item or a child item, like a doubly linked list. The rows are not sorted, but a parent item id must be smaller than a child item id.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Item Id', 'Parent Id', 'Child Id'],
                  data=[[1006, np.nan, np.nan],
                        [1001, np.nan, 1005],
                        [1004, 1003, 1007],
                        [1003, 1002, 1004],
                        [1005, 1001, np.nan],
                        [1002, np.nan, 1003],
                        [1007, 1004, np.nan]
                        ])
print(df)
#    Item Id  Parent Id  Child Id
# 0     1006        NaN       NaN
# 1     1001        NaN    1005.0
# 2     1004     1003.0    1007.0
# 3     1003     1002.0    1004.0
# 4     1005     1001.0       NaN
# 5     1002        NaN    1003.0
# 6     1007     1004.0       NaN
```

So the dataframe contains 3 chains:

- 1001 => 1005
- 1002 => 1003 => 1004 = > 1007
- 1006

**Question**

How to find the length of longest chain in this dataframe? (i.e. 3 in the given dataframe)

Comment: I would suggest using the information in the dataframe to create a graph using networkx, that probably has an algorithm already implemented for that kind of problem.

Comment: thanks @bli - i made a solution based on your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @bli's suggestion, I converted the dataframe to a directed graph using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html#pandas), and get the answer with `dag_longest_path()` and `dag_longest_path_length()`.

```py
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[~df['Child Id'].isna()], 'Item Id', 'Child Id', 
                          edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

**Output**

```py
>>> print(nx.dag_longest_path(G))
[1002, 1003, 1004, 1007.0]
>>> print(nx.dag_longest_path_length(G))
3
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that networkx even had `from_pandas*` methods.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, neither pandas nor the underlying numpy will be good at solving a graph question.

But you can represent each chain with a list, build a list of all the chains, and then sort it. I would use an auxilliary dict to link each item to its chain:

```
chains = []
seen = {}

for _, row in df.sort_values("Item Id").iterrows():
    itemId = row['Item Id']
    childId = row['Child Id']
    if itemId in seen:
        chain = seen[itemId]
    else:                                     # this is a new chain
        chain = seen[itemId] = [itemId]
        chains.append(chain)
    if not np.isnan(childId):                 # add the child to the end of the chain
        seen[childId] = chain
        chain.append(childId)
chains.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))             # and sort the list of chains
```

(This algorithm uses the property that a parent item id must be smaller than a child item id)

With your input dataframe is gives:

```
>>> print(chains)
[[1006.0], [1001.0, 1005.0], [1002.0, 1003.0, 1004.0, 1007.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take all the parents which are the ones with 'np.nan' in their parent Id. recursively check for each parent until it finds the longest chain. Or the reverse can be done too, look for the ones with 'np.nan' in their Child Id, they are the last part of the chain and recursively go back until there is no parent left.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. This is NOT optimized at all, but it will get you what you want, without recursion:

```
data = [[1006, None, None],
        [1001, None, 1005],
        [1004, 1003, 1007],
        [1003, 1002, 1004],
        [1005, 1001, None],
        [1002, None, 1003],
        [1007, 1004, None]
    ]


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, parent=None, child=None):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent
        self.child = child


nodes = {}
parent_ids = []

for entry in data:
    (itm, parent, child) = entry
    nodes[itm] = Node(itm, parent, child)
    if parent is None:
        parent_ids.append(itm)

for parent_id in parent_ids:
    chain = [str(parent_id)]
    node = nodes[parent_id]
    while node.child is not None:
        chain.append(str(node.child))
        node = nodes[node.child]
    print(" -> ".join(chain))
```

The output:

```
1006
1001 -> 1005
1002 -> 1003 -> 1004 -> 1007
```